# Get array value from array into another array foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need a help to solved my problem, I have a problem with detail as below:
I have two array which:

```
$array_one = array('php', 'mysql');
$array_two = array('sample', 'nothing', 'glass', 'table', 'door', 'mirror', 'wall');
```

I have foreach $array_two as below:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($array_two as $item){
    $data = $item . ' + php or mysql for in sequence';
    print_r($data);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

I want to get result as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sample php
    [1] => nothing mysql
    [2] => glass php
    [3] => table mysql
    [4] => door php
    [5] => mirror mysql
    [6] => wall php
)
```

How to do it, in squence php and mysql into foreach a array.

Note: The $array_two no limit data. above only example. And the $array_one maybe added one or two again later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$n_one = count($array_one);
foreach($array_two as $i => $item) {
    $data = $item. '+'. $array_one[$i % $n_one];
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach($array_two as $key=>$val){
  $result[] =  $val." ".$array_one[$key%2];
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/107365)

Comment: Hello, I just try another answer and solved, thanks for your help, I just get you a vote up....